# Hair magnet based on opp. Charges

Tags: voltage, design

As we know that a balloon attract hair, as it have negative charge and hairs have positive charge.
So my question is, can we make a permanent hair magnet by charging something negatively?if yes, how?

Comment: You've made a wrong assumption.  You get attraction of a dielectric (hair, paper, etc.) in a non-uniform electric field because of unequal charge distribution caused by the E-field.  (See figure 10-8 here.) http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_10.html

Answer (score 0):

In theory, yes, practically no.

To create a permanent charge, you will have to encapsulate it, as you do it in a EEPROM or Flash memory cell. This could work in an object with a ceramic or semiconductor based surface, where you could implant a charge.

Unfortunately you'd encounter adverse effects if you tried to do this practically.

Let's say you have a ceramic substrate providing a very good insulation. You somehow manage to implant a strong charge in a layer below the surface of the substrate and prevent other charges accumulating in the substrate. It will not take long, until through influence adverse charges will accumulate on the surface of the substrate annihilating the E-field of your implanted charges. 
Let's say you find a way to prevent the buildup of surface charges, you won't be able to prevent ions from the air being attracted to the substrate's surface, annihilating the far field of your charges once more.

Perhaps it might work in a perfect vacuum, but this is impractical, as you might realise.

Comment: It works pretty well for small charges, see electrets

Comment: Isn't there any negative ion generator, which continuosly produce the charge so as to balance lost charge

Comment: @PlasmaHH hmm, I forgot about electrets, but I think for sucking up hair it would not be sufficient, would it?

Comment: @vanshajwore do you refer to electrets or do you insinuate another  solution. For electrets: no, it's the basic property of electrets to hold their charge for ages.

Comment: Something similar to this, https://youtu.be/EvspL4kMY54

Comment: @Ariser: I don't know, maybe a lab version could, the strongest ones that are around that I know are used in electret air filters.

Comment: @vanshajwore there are numerous high voltage generator concepts which could act as a source for strong E-fields attracting hair, dust and so on. But this is not what the OP asked for.

Comment: Ok, will you plz suggest me the a way to make hair magnet using high voltage generator

Comment: @vanshajwore the comment section is the wrong place to deal with your request. You should ask another question. *that was the short answer*. The long one is: read the help, explaining how to ask good questions. You find it on top of this page under the "help" menu. You will learn there, that you should at least try Google to give you insight on your topic. EE.SE folks dislike to do all the work for you. You will also learn, that you have to describe your problem with more than three mere lines and that you should show own research and thinking.